# C++ Pointer Inquiry

Tags: c++, pointers, static, typedef

So I've been fooling around with statics, pointers and typedefs and I've run into a brick wall and was wondering if someone could offer some insight.

I have a class `Utils`with a `static ofstream` called `theLog` and I have another class `Work` that makes use of `Utils::theLog`. Here's the pertinent code:

#### Utils.h

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

// includes

class Utils {
public:
  static ofstream theLog;

  // other code 
}
#endif
```

#### Work.cpp

```
 // includes

typedef ofstream* pOfStream;
static pOfStream l = &(Utils::theLog); // l is a lowercase L

// constructor and destructor

void Work::doSomeWork() {
    (*l) << "Hello, world!\n";
}
// other code
```

This compiles and gives no runtime errors. However the reason for defining `pOfStream` was to eliminate the filling of my code with asterisks, parentheses and `Utils::theLog`. When I try replacing `(*l)` with just `l` as in: `l << "Hello, world!\n";` I get compiler errors. I'm assuming the reason being is that the operator `<<` takes precedence over `*`, even though `l` is of the type `pOfStream`, which is defined as being a pointer to an `ofstream` object, however the code is not implicitly written `*l << "Hello, world!\n";`.

My question being, is there a way to use the extraction operator `<<` without having to surround a pointer with parentheses and an asterisk? Also when you define a type like the above `pOfStream` and then assign a variable `var` to the type `pOfStream`, does the compiler just read through the code and replace any instance of `pOfStream` with `ofstream*`?

I've been searching SO and Google for the answer but I'm not exactly sure how to phrase the question.

Comment: You could overload the operator and define your own functionality for it

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really getting at with your question and the "`<<` takes precedence over `*`" business, but the point is that there isn't an `operator <<` for `ofstream *` and there is one for `ofstream`.

Comment: @hobbs I didn't realize `ofstream*` had no `<< operator` I thought that if `ofstream` had one then `ofstream*` would to. In reference to the precedence part, I had seen an example on the C++ Wiki where `int i = *p.num` does not compile because the `.` takes precedence over `*`, so you have to surround `*p` with parentheses, and for some reason I thought that my situation related to that in some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just take the reference of the stream, such as

```
ostream &l = Utils::theLog;
l << "Hello, World!\n";
```

In this way, you don't have to use pointers.